# User gets "Another user recalled or responded to this request" error when approving a record in Lightning

Tags: lightning, error, sharing, approval-process, approval-step

Our Approval process was working fine until yesterday, we started facing this error. Even though we have not made any changes in the setup. Even with admin profile we are facing same issue
"Another user recalled or responded to this request" error when approving a record in Lightning
Can anyone suggest what could possibly the reason?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Does user has access to object records ?

Comment: Yes access is not the issue here